# Difference between: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> and external PHP file in action attribute?

Tags: php, html, forms, echo, action

I have this code in my index.php file -

```
<form class="speaker-form" action="form.php" method="post">
```

Everywhere I am reading that my code should look like this -

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

I do want to link the external (form.php) file. Do I write the superglobal in the external file? I can't seem to find any examples of this being done.

Thanks.

Comment: this should works fine. create a form.php in same directory and access $_POST with needed parameters

Answer (score 0):

example :
save below as sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="test.php">
            <div id="Level1_Form"> <!--Use divs to space-->
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-1">
                    <p class="level1InputP">First Name: <span class="formError" id="FNameErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="fName"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-2">
                    <p class="level1InputP">Last Name: <span class="formError" id="LNameErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="lName"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-3">
                    <p class="level1InputP">E-Mail: <span class="formError" id="ErrorEmailP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="eMail"/>
                    <p id="ErrorEMailP"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-4">
                    <p class="level1InputP">Phone Number: <span class="formError" id="ErrorPhoneNumP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="phoneNumber"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

save below as test.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: $Jeff : this is just  ;) sample file to give an idea